# How to determine which button was submitted?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4, formbuilder

I have a form built with `FormBuilder` like

[image]

, which has one (submit) button on each row for removing entries.

When looking at the generated HTML code, the buttons have names in the scheme like

```
listForm[leadPartners][0][remove]
listForm[leadPartners][1][remove]
...
```

This makes sense to me so far.

The problem is, when the form gets submitted by one of the remove-buttons and i try to get the name of the button, to determine which button was the submitted one, through calling `$listForm->getClickedButton()->getName()`, the returned name is always `remove` and i can't find a way to get the number of the button to know to which of my entities it belongs to.

Question: How to know which button was pressed?

The form Type:

```
class LeadPartnerFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => LeadPartner::class,
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('remove', SubmitType::class);
    }
}
```

The relevant twig code

```
{% for partner in listForm.lead_partners %}
     <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-10" >{{ form_widget(partner.name) }}</div>
          <div class="col-2">{{ form_widget(partner.remove) }}</div>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Info: [I don't want to do this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-tags-to-be-removed).

Comment: Do your entities have Id's ? in which case you can add('id', HiddenType::class) to your form builder and get the id of the entity you are trying to remove.

Comment: @DennisdeBest Yes, i do. But how would adding the hidden field help? Because still the button would not convey the id.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by following official docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/multiple_buttons.html
But why would you need to do removal in this way? Symfony handles collection item removals pretty well, you can even use callbacks to handle them manually. There is no need to do this in such a way.

Comment: 1. This does not work, because - as i wrote - all the buttons have the same name after being submitted.
2. I explicitly stated, that i don't want to use the provided item collection removal.

Comment: And I am asking why you dont want to use that method? If you have done it properly buttons shouldnt be the same name, they would have collection index inside their name. And if you want to do everything in custom way, you then have to use JS and some kindof hidden field. For example add data attribute which indicates your record and after button click read that data and write into a hidden field. After form submission you will be able to handle hidden field value to determine which record to remove.